# Jquery add and remove class on scroll

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I need to find position of element and when scroll reached to element and element displayed in screen, highlight icon.

Script works but class adds very early, when block closer to bottom. I need add class when block closer to top.

My code:

```js
jQuery(window).scroll(function($) {
  var scrollDistance = jQuery(window).scrollTop();
  jQuery('.page-section').each(function(i) {
if (jQuery(this).position().top <= scrollDistance) {
  jQuery('h4 a').removeClass('active'); 
  jQuery('.navigation a').removeClass('active');
  jQuery('.navigation a').eq(i).addClass('active');

}
  });
}).scroll();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h4><a href="home">Home</a></h4>    
<ul class="navigation">
  <li><a href="#overview" class="">1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#employment" class="">2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#time" class="active">3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#payroll" class="">4</a></li>
  <li><a href="#further-reading">5</a></li>
</ul>

<div class= "page-section" id="home"></div>
<div class= "page-section" id="overview"></div>
<div class= "page-section" id="employment"></div>
<div class= "page-section" id="time"></div>
<div class= "page-section" id="payroll"></div>
<div class= "page-section" id="further-readin"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed it myself. Maybe someone helps it

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.sidbar-inner ul li a').click(function(event){
        $('.sidbar-inner ul li a').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
        thisAttrHref = $(this).attr('href');
        thisAttrHrefOffset = $(thisAttrHref).offset().top;
        $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:thisAttrHrefOffset});
    });  
 });    
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        $('.page-section').each(function(){
            pageSectionTop = $(this).offset().top - 80;
            if($(document).scrollTop() > pageSectionTop){
                thisOfs = $(this).attr('id');
                $('.page-section').removeClass('active');
                ActiveID = $(this).addClass('active').attr('id');       
                
            }
        });
        $('.sidbar-inner ul li').each(function(index, el){
            thisChildren = $(this).children('a');
            thisChildrenHref = $(this).children('a').attr('href');
            if(thisChildrenHref === '#'+ActiveID){
                $('h4 a').removeClass('active');
                $('.sidbar-inner ul li a').removeClass('active');
                $(thisChildren).addClass('active')
            }
            
        })
        
    });
```